# XML Marshalling on Java with custom wrapper

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, marshalling

Considering the following POJO:

```
public class User {
    private String name;
    /* + getter/setter */
}
```

And the following REST WebService:

```
@Path("Department")
public class DeptoREST {
    @GET @Path("{id}")
    public List<User> getEmployeesList( Integer id ) {
        return dao.fetchEmployeesFromDepto( id );
    }
}
```

This is the resulting output:

```
<users>
    <user><name>Usr 1</name></user>
    <user><name>Usr 2</name></user>
    <user><name>Usr 3</name></user>
</users>
```

Without a wrapper class, is it possible to change the ouput to be something like:

```
<employees>
    <employee><name>Usr 1</name></employee>
    <employee><name>Usr 2</name></employee>
    <employee><name>Usr 3</name></employee>
</employees>
```

Comment: Do you mind adding annotations to the `User` class?

Comment: @teppic do you mean adding `@XmlRootElement(name="employe")` to the user class? If so, then I do mind because I have 2 endpoints, one would be `<employe>` and the other `<user>`. I was wondering if it's possible to change only the tag name.

Answer (score 0):

You could wrap the list, rather than the individual `User` objects:

```
@XmlRootElement(name="employees")
public static class EmployeeList {
    @XmlElement(name = "employee")
    private List<User> users;

    public EmployeeList() {
        users = Collections.emptyList();
    }

    public EmployeeList(List<User> users) {
        this.users = users;
    }

    public List<User> getUsers() {
        return users;
    }
}
```

Then:

```
return new EmployeeList(dao.fetchEmployeesFromDepto( id ));
```

Comment: But this way you are implementing a wrapper class, and I would like to solve it without a wrapper. If it's impossible, please state so. If the only way to do that is with a wrapper, please could you take a look at my other question about wrapper class? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46270130/correct-marshalling-of-generic-list-of-items-using-jaxb